# Matrix is being converted in to a list in r

Tags: r, matrix

I am new to r, and I am having a problem with matrices. I have created a large matrix called out, but when I try to run it in the for loop, I get the error message that there are an improper amount of dimensions. After a lot of trial and error, I found out that I have a for loop that is converting it to a long list instead of a matrix. How do I stop this? Here is my code:

```
ComK<-seq(0,4,0.001) #Molarity
beta<-1 #Molarity/s
alpha<-1 #Inverse seconds
l<-length(ComK)
h<-4
out<-matrix(c(0),nrow = l,ncol=h)
# Finding All terms for the given ComK concentrations
for(i in 1:length(ComK)){
 out[i,1]<-ComK[i]
 out[i,2]<-prod(beta)
 out[i,3]<-deg(alpha,ComK[i])
 out[i,4]<-RHS(alpha,beta,ComK[i])
}
```

Comment: What are the packages used?

Comment: What are the classes of the objects you assign into the matrix?

Comment: deSolve is the only one specifically loaded. I am just trying to store numbers in it

Comment: @JohnColgan are you sure? Step into an instance of your `for` loop and check the type of each output from `deg` and `RHS` using `typeof`. Make sure they're also of length 1. Matrices can store characters and numeric, but each entry must be of the same type.

Comment: Thank You, @AdamO. That fixed it. RHS was a list